# How to paste 500 chunck of code in Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I need to pass this code

```
         observeEvent(input[[all_images_ID[1]]], {
           showModal(modal_dialog_function(1))

         }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

500 times in shiny server.

I already tried using `map`, `walk`, `for loops` but its not working.

Any idea? I am trying do create a file and create this code 500 times changing only the values in character and then pass in shiny as source.

But its not working...

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Don't paste.  Use [modules](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/) and the `apply` family of functions.  Here's a minimal demo, that should also help you with your other question...

```
library(shiny)

buttonUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  actionButton(ns("button"), "Click me!")
}

buttonServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      observeEvent(input$button, {
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            paste0("I am button ", id),
            title = "You clicked me!"
          )
        )
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(lapply(1:500, buttonUI))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  for (i in 1:500) {
    buttonServer(i)
  }
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks. Is it necessary using `tagList`function?