# Dynamically create inputs and and their observers in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app, I have the need to create an unknown number of inputs (with an unknown ID) and their corresponding observer.
The first task is quite trivial via `renderUI`, but the second task is a bit more tricky.

You could accomply task1 and task2 as follow:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

data <- list(
  "dtA" = data.table(p = paste0("a", 1:3), s = paste0("s", 1:3), t = paste0("t", 1:3))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "add UI and observers"),
  actionButton("remove", "remove UI and observer"),
  br(),
  uiOutput("myUI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  theinputs <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    # add inputs
    output$myUI <- renderUI({
      lapply(data, function(dt) {
        widgets <- lapply(1:nrow(dt), function(i) {
          ni <- div(
            style = "display: flex; flex-direction: row;",
            numericInput(
              inputId = paste0(dt$p[i], "_1"),
              label = paste0(dt$p[i]),
              value = 1,
              min = 1,
              max = 10
            ),
            numericInput(
              inputId = paste0(dt$p[i], "_2"),
              label = paste0(dt$t[i]),
              value = 2,
              min = 1,
              max = 10
            ),
            numericInput(
              inputId = paste0(dt$p[i], "_3"),
              label = paste0(dt$s[i]),
              value = 3,
              min = 1,
              max = 10
            ),
            br()
          )
          return(ni)
        })
        return(widgets)
      })
    })

    # add inputs' observers
    res <- list()
    for (d in 1:length(data)) {
      dt <- data[[d]]
      name <- names(data)[d]

      if (nrow(dt) != 0) {
        obs <- lapply(1:nrow(dt), function(i) {
          r <- reactive({
            list(
              input[[paste0(dt$p[i], "_1")]],
              input[[paste0(dt$p[i], "_2")]],
              input[[paste0(dt$p[i], "_3")]]
            )
          })

          assign(paste0(dt$p[i], "_0"), r)

          ob <- list()

          ob[[paste0(dt$p[i], "_0")]] <- observeEvent(get(paste0(dt$p[i], "_0"))(),
            {
              result <- input[[paste0(dt$p[i], "_1")]] + input[[paste0(dt$p[i], "_2")]] + input[[paste0(dt$p[i], "_3")]]
              print(paste0(dt$p[i], "_0: ", result))
            },
            ignoreInit = T, # not working???
          )
          return(ob)
        })

        res <- c(res, unlist(obs, recursive = F))
        rm(obs)
      }
    }

    theinputs(res)
  })

  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    # remove inputs' observers
    if (!is.null(unlist(theinputs()))) {
      lapply(theinputs(), function(x) {
        x$destroy()
        return(NULL)
      })
      theinputs(NULL)
    }
    # remove inputs
    output$myUI <- renderUI({
      NULL
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works just fine, however, if you have

```
data <- list(
  "dtA" = data.table(p = paste0("a", 1:3), s = paste0("s", 1:3), t = paste0("t", 1:3)),
  "dtB" = data.table(p = paste0("b", 1:2), s = paste0("s", 1:2), t = paste0("t", 1:2))
)
```

things go wrong, I get

> ```
> Warning: Error in get: object 'b1_0' not found
>   1: runApp
> Warning: Error in get: object 'b2_0' not found
>   1: runApp
> Warning: Error in get: object 'NA_0' not found
>   1: runApp
> ```

and I cannot figure out why....

**---EDIT---**

As pointed out by @Limey, modules could potentially be a better way to do this. However I end up with the same error

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

inputModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("inputs"))
  )
}

inputModule <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  ns <- session$ns
  observe({
    output$inputs <- renderUI({
      lapply(seq_along(data), function(d) {
        dt <- data[[d]]
        name <- names(data)[d]
        
        widgets <- lapply(1:nrow(dt), function(i) {
          ns_id <- paste0("module", name, i)
          tagList(
            div(
              style = "display: flex; flex-direction: row;",
              numericInput(
                inputId = ns(paste0(ns_id, "_1")),
                label = paste0(dt$p[i]),
                value = 1,
                min = 1,
                max = 10
              ),
              numericInput(
                inputId = ns(paste0(ns_id, "_2")),
                label = paste0(dt$t[i]),
                value = 2,
                min = 1,
                max = 10
              ),
              numericInput(
                inputId = ns(paste0(ns_id, "_3")),
                label = paste0(dt$s[i]),
                value = 3,
                min = 1,
                max = 10
              ),
              br()
            )
          )
        })
        do.call(tagList, widgets)
      })
    })
    
      for (d in 1:length(data)) {
        dt <- data[[d]]
        name <- names(data)[d]
        lapply(1:nrow(dt), function(i) {
          r <- reactive({
            list(
              input[[paste0("module", name, i, "_1")]],
              input[[paste0("module", name, i, "_2")]],
              input[[paste0("module", name, i, "_3")]]
            )
          })
          
          assign(paste0("module", name, i, "_0"), r)
          
          
          observeEvent(get(paste0("module", name, i, "_0"))(),
            {
              result <- input[[paste0("module", name, i, "_1")]] +
                input[[paste0("module", name, i, "_2")]] +
                input[[paste0("module", name, i, "_3")]]
              print(paste0("module", name, i, "_0: ", result))
            },
            ignoreInit = TRUE,
            ignoreNULL = FALSE
          )
        })
      }
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add UI and observers"),
  actionButton("remove", "Remove UI and observers"),
  br(),
  uiOutput("myUI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  theModule <- NULL
  moduleUI <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  output$myUI <- renderUI({
    moduleUI()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    data <- list(
      "dtA" = data.table(p = paste0("a", 1:3), s = paste0("s", 1:3), t = paste0("t", 1:3)),
      "dtB" = data.table(p = paste0("b", 1:2), s = paste0("s", 1:2), t = paste0("t", 1:2))
    )
    if (is.null(theModule)) {
      theModule <<- callModule(inputModule, "module1", data = data)
      moduleUI(inputModuleUI("module1"))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    if (!is.null(theModule)) {
      moduleUI(NULL)
      theModule <<- NULL
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    if (is.null(theModule)) {
      output$myUI <- renderUI({
        inputModuleUI("module1")
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Regardless of the approach, if I have just one of the two data.tables then the app works as it should, with two or more it crashes...

Comment: It may be "trivial" to proceed as you are for now, but it may also be worthwhile introducing a little additional complexity to start with in order to reduce complexity in the longer run.  This problem strikes me as a prime candidate for the use of [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).  My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77502541/how-to-paste-500-chunck-of-code-in-shiny-server/77502906#77502906) may be helpful.

Comment: It would also be helpful to rewrite your code to remove the dependency on the input text file.  When I do that, and run the app, I am unable to reproduce the error.  I get output that appears sensible, but I don't know if it's correct because you don't define your expected behaviour.

Comment: @Limey, I am not sure I understand your second comment. Anyhow, I was already experimenting with modules, but I ended up with the same error. See the edit in the first post.

Comment: My point is that, in order to start answering your question, I first have to create text file(s) in the right format, save them in the right format  and in the right location.  That takes time and is prone to error.  It would be easier (for me) and more robust (for both of us) if you made your code independent of external files.  In other words, if you removed the `fread`s and provided your data in `data.frame`s created within your app code.

Comment: @Limey sorry, bad habits, I have updated the code and made it independent

Comment: Thank you.  Alas, my first impression is that you are badly misusing the concept of modules.  There should be no need for `assign(paste0("module", name, i, "_0"), r)`, `get(paste0("module", name, i, "_0"))()`, `theModule <<- callModule(inputModule, "module1", data = data)` and the like.  In addition, you seem to be creating only a single module.  That rather misses the point.  This may take some time to sort out...